# Loop Through Pandas Dataframe and split into multiple dataframes based on unique column values

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe saved in a list. Is there a way to loop through the list to create separate dataframes based of a column value?

ex: Turn this

df

| ID | Colour | Transport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0902 | red | car |
| 0902 | blue | car |
| 0105 | red | car |
| 0105 | yellow | car |
| 0105 | orange | boat |

To this:

df1

| ID | Colour | Transport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0902 | red | car |
| 0902 | blue | car |

df2

| ID | Colour | Transport |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0105 | red | car |
| 0105 | yellow | car |
| 0105 | orange | boat |

I have searched for a way to do this but can't find it. Any ideas?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
df1 = df.loc[df['ID'] == 0902]
df2 = df.loc[df['ID'] == 0105]
```

Or this:

```
df1, df2 = [group for _, group in df.groupby('ID')]
```

Or if you want it dynamically:

```
dct = {f'df{idx}': group for _, group in df.groupby('ID')]}
print(dct)
```

Or:

```
dct = {}
for idx, v in enumerate(df['ID'].unique()):
    dct[f'df{idx}'] = df.loc[df['ID'] == v]

print(dct)
```

And print like this for specific dataframe:

```
print(dct['df1'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create variables `df1` and `df2` dynamically using `locals()`:

```
for i, (ID, subdf) in enumerate(df.groupby('ID'), 1):
    locals()[f'df{i}'] = subdf
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
     ID  Colour Transport
2  0105     red       car
3  0105  yellow       car
4  0105  orange      boat

>>> df2
     ID Colour Transport
0  0902    red       car
1  0902   blue       car
```

Or you can create a dictionary indexed by the group `ID`:

```
dfs = dict(list(df.groupby('ID')))
```

Output:

```
>>> dfs['0105']
     ID  Colour Transport
2  0105     red       car
3  0105  yellow       car
4  0105  orange      boat

>>> dfs['0902']
     ID Colour Transport
0  0902    red       car
1  0902   blue       car
```